# AWS Lambda Timeout when making Https request with NAT Gateway in place

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, aws-nat-gateway

I have a containerized Lambda deployed that uses the latest image from ECR. I have also already setup the networking with the following:

| Subnets | Route Table |
| --- | --- |
| private-1. | private-route |
| private-2. | private-route |
| public-0. | public-route. |

`Subnet CIDRs`

**private-1**: 172.31.32.0/20

**private-2**: 172.31.48.0/20

`Private Route Table`

| Destination | Target |
| --- | --- |
| 172.31.0.0/16 | local. |
| 0.0.0.0/0. | nat-xxx |

`Public Route Table`

| Destination | Target |
| --- | --- |
| 172.31.0.0/16 | local. |
| 0.0.0.0/0. | igw-xxx |

The Nat Gateway is associatd with the public-1 subnet.

`Security Group`

All Traffic Inbound and Outbound is allowed for now (for debugging).

`Lambda Configuration`

| Subnets. | Security Groups |
| --- | --- |
| private 1 & 2 | sg-xxx. |

My problem is after I set up this configuration I was able to get access, then I added configuration to talk to a peered vpc for a database connection and that also worked. But immediately following It stopped working. So my confusion is why is it sporadic? I'll randomly change security groups and redo networking and it works once then stops. This is the error I constantly see now which is the first few lines of the lambda invocation.

`"errorMessage": "HTTPSConnectionPool(host='maps.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /maps/api/geocode/json?`

Comment: Have you tried connecting to other domains?

Comment: When you setup your maps google API, did you have to whitelist any IP addresses?